# parameter in url can not be read by form

Tags: django, forms

I am reading the book “django by example” and try the example "bookmarks" in it. for the image book I am confused.Because the form can't access the parameters value from django. The code is below:

```
 views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import ImageCreateForm

@login_required
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():   
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request,'Image added successfully')
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    return render(request,'images/image/create.html',{'section':'images','form':form})

forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Image
import urllib

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.utils.text import slugify

class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title','url','description')
        widgets = {
            'url':forms.HiddenInput,
        }
    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        valid_extensions = ['jpg','jpeg']
        extension = url.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower()
        if extension not in valid_extensions:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not match valid image extensions')
        return url

    def save(self,force_insert=False,force_update=False,commit=True):
        image = super(ImageCreateForm,self).save(commit=False)
        image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        image_name = '{}.{}'.format(slugify(image.title),image_url.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower())
        #response = request.urlopen(image_url)
        response = urllib.urlopen(image_url)
        image.image.save(image_name,ContentFile(response.read()),save=False)
        if commit:
            image.save()
        return image

create.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Bookmark an image {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Bookmark an image</h1>
    <img src ="{{request.GET.url}}" class = "image-preview">
    <form action = "." method = "post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type = "submit" value ="Bookmark it!">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

the url what I used is 
/images/create/?title=%20Django%20and%20Duke&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.
wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F8%2F85%2FDjango_Reinhardt_and_Duke_
Ellington_%28Gottlieb%29.jpg
and the result shown is ,also the picture has been shown but it is still said can't find the url and title. Could someone help me ? thank you
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ka0.png)

Comment: In `else`  change `form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)` to `form = ImageCreateForm()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove data parameter from form, in the if statement of request.method == "POST"

```
form = ImageCreateForm(request.POST)
```

Also in the else statement,

```
form = ImageCreateForm()
```

Put the csrf token above the form variable.

These are recommended way of writing django views and templates.

Now the form.is_valid() is never been true, ie, the code under is never been executed.

The problem could be two things.

1. In models.py, url field in the model Image should have blank= True, for when the form is posted, the url field is allowed to be blank. I don't see your models.py, so I can't say anything about that.
2. Or the field url should be dynamically filled from the request.GET.url . I don't see any code regarding the autofilling of url field, so it could be the problem.

Either way, the error message indicates that the url field can't be left blank in the form. By doing one of the above, the form can be validated and the rest of your code will execute.

**EDIT**

From what you said, I think you may need to manually render the form in html, rather than letting django do the form rendering.
Because, you need to get the url from your request.GET.url, then post it to the view through the url field,

Maybe something like this,

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="url" id="id_url" value"{{ request.GET.url }}"/>
  <label for="id_title">Title :</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="id_title" />
  <label for="id_description">Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="description" id="id_description" />
</form>
```

But, doing it this way, makes the customization you have done on your modelform would be unnecessary. For what you need and from what you require, I think this would be a better option, I think.
I can't think of a better solution. If you came up with something better than this, please feel free to let me know..

Comment: thank you .I tried that but the result didn't change,still can't find the url. btw,what is the differenct between form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST) and  form = ImageCreateForm(request.POST)

Comment: Also put the csrf token above the form variable

Comment: I think url is right:
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$',views.image_create,name='create'),
]

Comment: Your url field is hidden and is left blank, why would you hide the field? The field is a model attribute isn't it?

Comment: even if it is not hidden, we can't get the value.

Comment: There's no value in the url field, that's the problem

Comment: there are url and title in the url, even the image is shown from the url.

Comment: the image is showing because <img src="{{request.GET.url}}">, but the form has a hidden input field for url, which is not filled..

Comment: if it is,how could I do to get the url for form?thank you.

Comment: The url {{request.GET.url}} is the url want to save, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

in the else parameter of your view edit the **form = ImageCreateForm(request.GET)**  because you are parsing your data in get method and your are using it in get method also in your create.html as

```
<img src = {{ request.GET.url }} >
```